# Changing 'the' to 'The' in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to change all incidences of 'the' to 'The' in a specific column of a database table. I only need to change the word 'the' and not all incidences where the letters 'the' appear (e.g. in the word 'therefore'). To put this into some context, I have a bunch of addresses e.g. The Willows, the Big House, the Smith Farm in the table. In this example, the last two incidences of 'the' would need changing to 'The'.

I have tried various SQL scripts, one of which I know works (I've tried it on a small amount of data). This script is shown below. However, when I run the script on the full test database it takes forever to run and slows down the entire server.

I'm therefore trying to find a script which pulls out any addresses that have 'the' shown in lower case, and then I can then use my working SQL to alter just these records. An attempt at writing such a script is shown below, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

The working code (the one that takes forever) is:

```
SET ADDRESSLINE1 = replace(ADDRESSLINE1, ' the ', ' The ')
```

I've tried this code to pull out just those records with 'the', but this produces no records at all:

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE addressline1 COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE ' the '
```

I would expect that the second script shown above would pull out any addresses that have 'the' instead of 'The'.

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: And if a value starts with `'the ...`, don't you want to replace it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the code that works is:

```
UPDATE addresses
    SET ADDRESSLINE1 = replace(ADDRESSLINE1, ' the ', ' The ');
```

If so, I would recommend adding a `WHERE` clause to speed the query:

```
UPDATE addresses
    SET ADDRESSLINE1 = replace(ADDRESSLINE1, ' the ', ' The ')
    WHERE ADDRESSLINE1 LIKE '% the %';
```

You don't specify the database, but some databases will update *all* rows -- including logging the changed values -- even when values do not change.